# How do you get the name of a sheet given only a hyperlink gid id value?

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I am new to google sheets and trying to figure out how given a hyperlink to another sheet I can populate the name from it.
I have a bunch of rows with a column field that contains a gid value like #gid=1905813383 and when

I hover over it I see it is a link to another sheet with a name but I would rather see the name of the sheet in that column or another new column than a link to it.
Anyone know how this can be done in google sheets?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

add this script:

```
function SH() {
try {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  var out = new Array( sheets.length+1 ) ;
  for (var i = 1 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ ) out[i-1] = 
  [sheets[i-1].getSheetId() , sheets[i-1].getName()];
  return out}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" }}
```

then use simple VLOOKUP formula:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(HYPERLINK(A20:A25, VLOOKUP(A20:A25, {"#gid=", ""}&SH(), 2, ))))
```

[image]